# Postfix able to receive email but not able to send it

Tags: centos, postfix, ant

I had postfix running on my machine(comes with centos minimal), but today I configured it to use my domain for the sake of example this is my domain name `example.com` . Here is my config :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10485760
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relayhost = smtp.$mydomain
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unknown_client,permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

I need one email account to be able to send emails (password retrievals etc.). I read today somewhere that if you create unix account postfix will recognize it as email address so if your account username was `ant` your email would be `ant@example.com`.

So I tested that and tried to send email to `ant@example.com` and I successfully received mail.

When I try to send the email with ant task script, I'm not able to connect :

```
Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.example.com, port: 25; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I'm able to telnet to localhost :

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a firewall somewhere what is denying incoming connections to postfix.

Look at the output of:

```
iptables-save
```

Comment: hello it's disabled, and I think the message would be that connection is refused but it's timeout in my case don't really get why

Comment: if you have a firewall somewhere what is dropping packets you get "connection timeout"

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the DNS. Either `mail.example.com` must resolve to 127.0.0.1 or you must add the IP for mail.example.com to `mynetworks`.

Comment: I am not sure if that is right. He is getting "connection timed out". Look at the java exception.